# SWT Browser widget with Eclipse 4 RCP application

Tags: browser, eclipse-plugin, widget, swt, eclipse-rcp

Please help to get started with Eclipse 4 RCP.
Set task is to create simple application with imbedded browser (using SWT Browser widget)

This [Lars Vogel's Eclipse 4 RCP tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#tutorial_e4wizard) is used.
Created [application is on GitHub](https://github.com/PaulVI/Eclipse4RCPwithSWTBrowserWidget). Now I want to [add SWT browser widget](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/10/29/javascript-swt-browser-widget/).

I added [class](https://github.com/PaulVI/Eclipse4RCPwithSWTBrowserWidget/blob/master/src/com/example/e4/rcp/browser/View.java).

Unsurprisingly, now application doesn't start:
Added class seems quite of different nature. Seems I am missing some points about Eclipse 4 and SWT connection.

I have read the basics about Eclipse RCP before.

Here are docs: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/ and [JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html), but they don't explain.

**Where should be my next steps to? What to read?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `ViewPart` is only used in Eclipse 3 RCP. Instead your part class should 1) be connected to the application model, as described in Vogella's tutorial; 2) create controls in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`, with a signature like `public void createControls(Composite parent)`. His example in Section 17.2 even contains a `Browser`, but it doesn't matter *which* SWT widgets you want to use: the process is the same.
2. You can't expect to find anything about RCP in SWT documentation! Look at the RCP documentation instead.
3. > I have read the basics about Eclipse RCP before.

   Try to forget them, they likely will just confuse you. Eclipse 4 RCP does very many things differently. Of course, SWT and JFace haven't changed, so you can still use what you read about them.

Comment: Could you add up some links?

Comment: Where is RCP documentation?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/nav/2_0, but it doesn't differentiate well between old and new RCP.